# Create % of unfiltered total in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to calculate a % of total from the unfiltered total rather than the filtered total. So I have four rows like this unfiltered:

```
Column1  Column2   Column3
-------  -------   -------    
Blah       1         17%
Blah       2         33%
Blah       1         17%
Blah       2         33%
Total      6        100%
```

I want to filter by Column 2 where the value is greater than 1, so I'm looking for the percentage column to calculate the percentage based on 6, but when I filter, it's only doing it on 4. So here's what I'm looking for

```
Column1  Column2   Column3
-------  -------   -------    
Blah       2         33%
Blah       2         33%
Total      4         66%
```

But this is what I'm getting:

```
Column1  Column2   Column3
-------  -------   -------    
Blah       2         50%
Blah       2         50%
Total      4         100%
```

Is there any way to do what I want in the field settings dropdown or can this be done with a calculated column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a Pivot Table with your data, use `Column 1` and `Column 2` for your Row Labels and `Column 3` for your values and it'll automatically subtotal and total your values for you.

The left table shows your base data.  The middle table shows unfiltered data.  The right table shows your data filtered >1 (without the percentage format applied).

[image: PivotSubtotals]

Answer (score 0):

As the Grand Total for your dataset remains fixed no matter how you slice the data using a pivot, you can make use of a **Calculated Field** to calculate the percentage of the item **whilst holding the grand total fixed**.

To do this:

1. Note down your source dataset's Grand Total, in your example this is `6`
2. Go to the **Fields, Items, & Sets** item on the ribbon bar and select **Calculated Field...**
3. Type in a name for your column, e.g. "Fixed % of Grand Total"
4. Type in a calculation that hard-codes your dataset's grand total, but calculates the percentage using a field reference to your value field. In your example this would be  `Col2 / 6`

The benefit of this approach is that the percentage works for any row groupings that you make use of in your pivot, without having to have each item's percentage calculated in your original dataset. In your example, this would mean that you can drop `Col3`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a field that calculates the total of column 1 insensitive to your filter settings:

   `B2 = SUM(Table1[Column2])`

   (I recommend placing this cell above your table so that adding rows via pasting doesn't make any trouble.)
2. Define the percentage column (Column3) via the formula:

   `=[@Column2]/$B$2`