# Pivot Table to Show Percent SUCCESS Scores ONLY

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

How would I adjust the pivot table to show only the percent of scores with SUCCESS and hide the FAILS?  Hiding the fails changes the SUCCESS scores to all 100%.  I can hide rows in the pivot table,  but that is too tedious.[EXAMPLE with FAILs hidden using row-by-row method]

Doug in York PA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create % of unfiltered total in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/465968/create-of-unfiltered-total-in-excel)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're looking at? It's hard to answer your question from this description.